# Programmatically determine maximum command line length with Python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

Does anyone know a portable way for Python to determine a system's maximum command line length?  The program I'm working on builds a command and feeds it to subprocess.  For systems with smaller command line length maximums, it is possible that the command will be too long.  If I can detect that, the command can be broken up to avoid exceeding the maximum length, but I've not found a (portable) way to determine the maximum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ask [sysconf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sysconf):

```
os.sysconf('SC_ARG_MAX')
```

Comment: Now why couldn't I find that?  Thanks!  Alas, it doesn't work on my Windows system, but that may be okay.  However, I expect I'll need to make it work on a Mac, even though I don't have access to one.  Do you know if sysconf is available on OS X?

Comment: The docs state this is for Unix only (both Mac and Unix for <= Python2.5). Also the dictionary lookup is not required, `os.sysconf('SC_ARG_MAX')` also works.